# Laravel form request validation priority

Tags: php, laravel, validation, intervention

In my Laravel 5.6 app, I have a controller with a `store` method:

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image as ImageHandler;

public function store(StoreFoo $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $toResize = ImageHandler::make($request->validated()->file('image')->getRealPath());
    }
}
```

My `StoreFoo` class validates that the `image` field is an image:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'image' => 'image'
    ];
}
```

I would expect that when I try to upload a file which is not an image, the validator would catch it and return an error. Instead the code inside the `store` method is run, which produces an "Unsupported image type" exception from Intervention.

Why does the validator not catch this beforehand, and how can I make it work this way?

Comment: What is the name and type of file you're uploading?

Comment: @RossWilson `test.mp3`

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question. That produces the same result.

Comment: validated() returns an array, that's not the right usage.  FormRequest objects have to pass before it even reaches your controller method, so it must be passing validation for some reason.

Comment: @Devon That's useful information, thanks. I can't see how it could pass the `image` rule though.

Comment: @GluePear, you don't have image required.  Have you ensured that's the correct input name?  What does `dd($request->all())` output?

Comment: @Devon That's because it's not required. But when I add `required` it doesn't change the result. But your hint helped: I added that `dd()` command in the controller method, and it wasn't hit. Which showed me that the `Intevention` error must have been coming from the form request (which uses `Intervention` in another validation rule). So that's the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your request file:

```
'image' => 'nullable|file|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',
```

Of course, feel free to add whatever other mimes you will accept.